# Is it possible to do stealth takedowns other than with sniper rifles?

Tags: jagged-alliance-3

Trying to wrap my head around stealth in the game. It is fairly easy to perform stealth kills with silenced sniper rifles, by aiming down a headshot that does tons of damage with a single hit.

Is it possible to perform stealth kills with other weapons as well? I haven't really managed so far, given that other weapons usually don't do enough damage to reliably take an enemy down in a single hit.

I can still see the use of silencers on other weapons than sniper rifles, because even if you do engage a single enemy/small group, you can sometimes take them down before alerting everyone else. But they don't really seem useful for stealth kills - sneaking up close on an enemy and taking them out with a silenced pistol or SMG doesn't seem like an option. Perhaps there is a flanking bonus if you attack from a stealth position?

What about melee? Is it even possible to get close enough to do stealth melee (other than throwing knives)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've found out myself:

Apart from sneaking and using silenced weapons, it is all about the DPS you can hand out in a single round and if it's enough to kill the target. So it is possible to do it with pistols and even knives - you can do stealth melee take-downs by marking an enemy as the target then just sneak your character close.

However, these tactics mainly work early on in the game. Later on when enemies wear more armor and helmets, sniper rifles aiming for headshots is basically the only feasible way to get stealth kills without alarming everyone.

There are perks you can pick that make a character hit harder for stealth attacks and there are scope mods etc that give such bonuses as well. These can be used inside combat as well as during sneak up before combat. So it is actually a somewhat feasible tactic to have a character train for stealth, then during combat let them hit hard from stealth mode, then sneak back behind cover and hide again. Also useful for flanking.

However when sneaking in combat, it isn't always obvious which characters the enemy has spotted. If you are standing in the open and the game says you are sneaking, an enemy could still be spotting you and hit you during their turn.

In my current playthrough I'm using Mouse for full stealth build. Early on her marksmanship is too poor to be trusted with rifles, but she did fine sneaking close with silenced pistols. I tried to use silenced SMGs but they don't seem very suitable for stealth kills, more so for the "in and out of view" tactics during combat described above. Towards end game she has all stealth perks and heavily modded rifles, capable of shooting pretty much every foe with a single stealth attack.